# compile error when using cv::minMaxLoc() on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, opencv

I am using OpenCV on iOS, the project works fine and can detect harris corners but when I try to use the following line I get a compile error:

```
cv::minMaxLoc(cornerStrength,&minStrength,&maxStrength);
```

The error from xcode is:

**Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___udivmodsi4", referenced from:
      cv::minMaxIdx(cv::_InputArray const&, double*, double*, int*, int*, cv::_InputArray const&)in OpenCV(stat.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

Any advice much appreciated as I cant find a way past this at the moment.

Cheers, 
Fraser

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LLVM GCC 4.x, try changing the compiler to Apple LLVM 3.x, that did the trick for me.